# Crash :com.apple.network.connections EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000036

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, crash, cfnetwork

Since the release of iOS16.1.0 and iOS16.1.1, I have received reports from iOS16.1.0 and iOS16.1.1 users about the crash problem. Later, I discovered that this problem occurred only iOS16.1.0 and later. This problem does not occur to all users ，I have tried several methods (such as using different versions of xcode build App), but still not solved...

Here are the crash track caught by firebase：
Crash :com.apple.network.connections EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000036

```
Crashed: com.apple.network.connections
0  libxpc.dylib                   0x16020 _xpc_dictionary_insert + 96
1  Network                        0x908504 nw_path_snapshot_agents + 292
2  Network                        0x907960 nw_path_snapshot_path + 192
3  Network                        0x9257b8 nw_path_necp_update_evaluator + 756
4  Network                        0x924aa4 nw_path_necp_check_for_updates + 1268
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x746c _dispatch_continuation_pop + 504
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1aa58 _dispatch_source_invoke + 1588
8  libdispatch.dylib              0xd4f8 _dispatch_workloop_invoke + 1780
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x16e10 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xdf8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb98 start_wqthread + 8

com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xb48 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x13008 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x13248 mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x108c mach_msg + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x7aaf0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5  CoreFoundation                 0x7bd34 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6  CoreFoundation                 0x80ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7  GraphicsServices               0x1368 GSEventRunModal + 164
8  UIKitCore                      0x3a23d0 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
9  UIKitCore                      0x3a2034 UIApplicationMain + 340
10 xxxxxx                         0x44ea24 main + 14 (main.m:14)
11 ???                            0x1d6e8c960 (缺少)

other thread ......
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: app crash ,the crash stack are what I wrote above

Comment: When will this crash occur? is it on the launch or while yo do any kind processes? Also please share the line of code which causes the crash.

Comment: It crashes randomly, depending on the stack and the network request, it can't be replicated, and it's only on iOS16.Apple says it's their network.framework problem, but I'm not sure it's theirs

 https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/720350

Comment: Hello! Were you able to solve this issue? I've been having this issue for months now. I have a lot of CFNetwork-related crashes that happen on iOS 16 only.